# Apache Port Redirection

Tags: apache, redirect, webserver, port

I have some trouble concerning Apache Webserver 2.4.7. I want to redirect some pages to another port (doesn't matter which one, I choose 82). Therefore, I edited the VirtualHosts as follows:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:82>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/hpc_test/web/trunk/
ServerName localhost
<Directory /var/www/html/hpc_test/web/trunk/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The redirection works fine but the new DocumentRoot does not. Some SSI commands are used assuming that /var/www/html/hpc_test/web/trunk/ is the DocRoot. Unfortunately, /var/www/html/ is considered as DocRoot for port 82.

Does any Apache expert can tell me if there's anything else I have to do? I studied the documentation and followed those instructions.

Cheers

Comment: Have you added `Listen 82` in the ports.conf file in your apache directory?

Comment: Yes, Apache is listening to port 82

Answer (score 0):

First check if apache correctly listen in the port 82 :

```
netstat -laputen|grep 82
```

In your web-browser, do you use http://localhost:82 ?

Because you just listen to **ServerName localhost**, if you try with an other domain, apache going to redirecting in your default vHost